# Border-radius bug in firefox

Tags: firefox, css

I've some problem with border-radius function in firefox.
When i apply, it makes some kind of space, or border around the item.
Can somebody tell me that this is a firefox bug or is there some resolve for that?

Here is the problem:
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMLNd/2/)

The

```
border-radius:50%;
```

line makes that, i am sure.

Comment: it looks fine to me, looks like we need some snapshot proving what's wrong on your side.

Comment: I believe it is a bug, maybe this is relevant: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=466572 -- Note that it's not the border-radius alone creating this side-effect - without box-shadow it looks fine.

Comment: it happens just in firefox. other browsers paint the elements differently. but if it is a bug, then is there some trick i can use for hide that?

Comment: @KingKing Each browser has its pros and cons, for instance, on windows, firefox is much better at rendering fonts than Chrome. No one browser is the best at everything, but firefox is the only truly open software and having multiple options is always a good thing. Your comment looks more like a rant than constructive feedback.

Comment: here is another fix for you http://jsfiddle.net/JMLNd/7/ Although if you want to add some text to the center of the circle, we have to add the text to the `:before` element, otherwise we have to send the `:before` element to the back, however doing so will create a small light border around the circle (blended by the shadow of the main circle).

Comment: in firefox use the "-moz-border-radius:" instead

Comment: @kamuken really? just tried that in the latest version of FF and the result is a square (radius = 0), interesting.

Comment: Last time I saw `-moz-border-radius`, I think I was still playing with a rattle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that this is a FF issue at rendering shadows with `border-radius`.
You could try this simple trick :

[The demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JMLNd/3/)

Basically, you apply the grey shadow on the parent `li`, make it a bit finer and then move a bit the `a.ch-item` child in order to make it go over the gap.

```
.ch-grid > li {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 198px;
    height: 198px;
}
.ch-item {
    position: relative; 
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
}
```

Of course, this is just for the idea. You might also want to apply the hover effect on the `li` element itself and move it 1px down and right to have a better result.

**Edit :** a [better result](http://jsfiddle.net/JMLNd/4/)